# Explanation of importing Python classes

Tags: python, import, module

So I know this could be considered quite a broad quesiton, for which I am sorry, but I'm having problems understanding the whole importing and `__init__` and `self.` things and all that... I've tried reading through the Python documentation and a few other tutorials, but this is my first language, and I'm a little (a lot) confused.

So far through my first semester at university I have learnt the very basics of Python, functions, numeric types, sequence types, basic logic stuff. But it's moving slower than I would like, so I took it upon myself to try learn a bit more and create a basic text based, strategy, resource management sorta game inspired by Ogame.

First problem I ran into was how to define each building, for example each mine, which produces resources. I did some research and found classes were useful, so I have something like this for each building:

```
class metal_mine:

    level = 1

    base_production = 15
    cost_metal = 40
    cost_crystal = 10
    power_use = 10

    def calc_production():
        metal_mine.production = A formula goes here

    def calc_cost_metal():
        etc, same for crystal

    def calc_power_use():
        metal_mine.power_use = blah blah

    def upgrade():
        various things
        solar_plant.calc_available_power()
```

It's kinda long, I left a lot out. Anyway, so the kinda important bit is that last bit, you see when I upgrade the mine, to determine if it has enough power to run, I calculate the power output of the solar plant which is in its own class (`solar_plant.calc_output()`),  which contains many similar things to the metal mine class. If I throw everything in the same module, this all works fantastically, however with many buildings and research levels and the likes, it gets very long and I get lost in it.

So I tried to split it into different modules, so one for mines, one for storage buildings, one for research levels, etc. This makes everything very tidy, however I still need a way to call the functions in classes which are now part of a different module. My initial solution was to put, for example, `from power import *`, which for the most part, made the `solar_plant` class available in the `metal_mine` class. I say for the most part, because depending on the order in which I try to do things, sometimes it seems this doesn't work. The `solar_plant` class itself calls on variables from the `metal_mine` class, now I know this is getting very spagetti-ish..but I don't know of any better conventions to follow yet.

Anyway, sometimes when I call the `solar_plant` class, and it in turn tries to call the `metal_mine` class, it says that `metal_mine` is not defined, which leads me to think somehow the modules or classes need to be initialized? There seems to be a bit of looping between things in the code. And depending on the order in which I try and 'play the game', sometimes I am unintentionally doing this, sometimes I'm not. I haven't yet been taught the conventions and details of importing and reloading and all that..so I have no idea if I am taking the right approach or anything.

Provided everything I just said made sense, could I get some input on how I would properly go about making the contents of these various modules freely available and modifiable to others? Am I perhaps trying to split things into different modules which you wouldn't normally do, and I should just deal with the large module? Or am I importing things wrong? Or...?

And on a side note, in most tutorials and places I look for help on this, I see classes or functions full of self.something and the **init** function..can I get a explanation of this? Or a link to a simple first-time-programmer's tutorial?

==================UPDATE=================

Ok so too broad, like I thought it might be. Based on the help I got, I think I can narrow it down.

I sorted out what I think need to be the class variables, those which don't change - `name`, `base_cost_metal`, and `base_cost_crystal`, all the rest would depend on the players currently selected building of that type (supposing they could have multiple settlements).

To take a snippet of what I have now:

```
class metal_mine:

    name = 'Metal Mine'

    base_cost_metal = 60
    base_cost_crystal = 15

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.production = 30
        self.cost_metal = 60
        self.cost_crystal = 15
        self.power_use = 0
        self.efficiency = 1

    def calc_production(self):
        self.production = int(30 + (self.efficiency * int(30 * self.level * 1.1 * self.level)))

    def calc_cost_metal(self):
        self.cost_metal = int(metal_mine.base_cost_metal * 1.5 ** self.level)
```

So to my understanding, this is now a more correctly defined class? I define the instance variables with their starting values, which are then changed as the user plays.

In my main function where I begin the game, I would create an instance of each mine, say, `player_metal_mine = metal_mine()`, and then I call all the functions and variables with the likes of

```
>>> player_metal_mine.level
0
>>> player_metal_mine.upgrade()
>>> player_metal_mine.level
1
```

So if this is correctly defined, do I now just import each of my modules with these new templates for each building? and once they are imported, and an instance created, are all the new instances and their variables contained within the scope(right terminology?) of the main module, meaning no need for new importing or reloading?

Provided the answer to that is yes, I do just need to import, what method should I use? I understand there is just `import mines` for example, but that means I would have to use `mines.player_metal_mine.upgrade()` to use it, which is a tiny bit more typing thanusing the likes of `from mines import *`, or more particularly, `from mines import metal_mine`, though that last options means I need to individually import every building from every module. So like I said, provided, yes, I am just importing it, what method is best?

**==================UPDATE 2=================** ***(You can probably skip the wall of text and just read this)***

So I went through everything, corrected all my classes, everything seems to be importing correctly using `from module import *`, but I am having issues with the scope of my variables representing the resource levels.

If everything was in 1 module, right at the top I would declare each variable and give it the beginning value, e.g. `metal = 1000`. Then, in any method of my classes which alters this, such as upgrading a building, costing resources, or in any function which alters this, like the one which periodically adds all the production to the current resource levels, I put `global metal`, for example, at the top. Then, within the function, I can call and alter the value of metal no problem.

However now that I am importing these classes and functions from various modules all into 1 module, functions cant find these variables. What I thought would happen was that in the process of importing I would basically be saying, take everything in this module, and pretend its now in this one, and work with it. But apparently that's not what is happening.

In my main module, I import all my modules using `from mines import *` for example and define the value of say, `metal`, to be `1000`. Now I create an instance of a metal mine, `metal_mine_one = metal_mine(), and I can call its methods and variables, e.g.

```
>>> metal_mine_one.production
30
```

But when I try call a method like `metal_mine_one.upgrade()`, which contains `global metal`, and then `metal -= self.cost_metal`, it give me an error saying metal is not defined. Like I said, if this is all in 1 module, this problem doesn't happen, but if I try to import things, it does.

So how can I import these modules in a way which doesn't cause this problem, and makes variables in the global scope of my main module available to all functions and methods within all imported modules?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial about object-oriented programming in Python. Specifically about the difference between **class variables** and **instance variables**. You're defining a bunch of class variables in `metal_mine`, when what you really want are instance variables. Creating instance variables will require you to use `__init__` and `self.`, etc. See this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 3):

First a little background on object oriented programming. i.e. classes. You should think of a class like a blueprint, it shows how to make something. When you make a class it describes how to make an object to the program. a simple class in python might look like this.

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, bars_starting_value):
    self.bar = bars_starting_value

  def print_bar(self):
    print(self.bar)
```

This tells python how to make a foo object. The **init** function is called a constructor. It is called when you make a new foo. The self is a way of referencing the foo that is running the function. In this case every foo has its own bar which can be accessed from within a foo by using self.bar. Note that you have to put a self as the first argument of the function definition this makes it so those functions belong to a single foo and not all of them.

One might use this class like this:

```
my_foo = foo(15)
my_other_foo = foo(100)
foo.print_bar()
foo.bar = 20
print(foo.bar)
my_other_foo.print_bar()
```

This would output

```
15
20
100
```

As far as imports go. They take all things that are defined in one file and move them to be defined in another. This is useful if you put the a class definition in a file you can import it into your main program file and make objects from there.

As far as making variables available to others, you could pass the power that has been generated from all the generators to the mine's function to determine if it has enough power.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm familiar with the blueprint aspect of classes, initially I tried it this way, however each mine, for example, has its own formula for calculating cost, production, etc. The only way around this I could think of was to have a variable which was a string version of the equation needed to calculate each thing, but this then needed the use of eval() to turn that string into a usable equation for the functions in that class, and I have read eval() should be a last resort, so I came up with this approach, where each building was its own class with specifically written functions to calculate this

Answer (score 2):

A lot of things to cover here.. **init** is a builtin method that is automatically called when an instance of a class is created. In the code you provided you've created a class, now you need to create an instance of that class. A simpler example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print "this is called when you create an instance of this class"
    def a_method(self):
          return True

class_instance = Test()
>>> "this is called when you create an instance of this class"
class_instance.a_method()
>>> True
```

The first argument in a class method is *always itself. By convention we just call that argument 'self'. Your methods did not accept any arguments, make sure they accept self (or have the decorator @staticmethod above them). Also, make sure you refer to attributes (in you case methods) by `self.a_method` or `class_instance.a_method`